# How to export date loaded asynchronously from Node.js module

Tags: node.js, module, async.js

I am struggling with the following module fetch.js which invokes a child process that generates output in multiple files. I would like this module to return a JSON containing that output.

```
    var util = require('util');
    const path = require('path');
    const fs = require('fs');

    const path1 = path.resolve(__dirname, 'out', 'file1');
    const path2 = path.resolve(__dirname, 'out', 'file2');

    let out1, out2;

    function generate() {
       var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
       var prog = spawn('prog', [<arguments>]);

       prog.on('exit', function (code) {
       if (code != 0) {
           console.log('Compilation failed.');
       } else {
          out1 = fs.readFileSync(path1, 'utf8');
          out2 = fs.readFileSync(path2, 'utf8');
       }
    })

    prog.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
       console.log(data);
    })


    return {out1, out2}
}


module.exports = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
   resolve(generate());
});
```

In main I do the following

```
const promise = require('./fetch');
promise.then((o1, o2) => {
   console.log('O = ' + typeof o1);
})
```

I know that the problem is that return from generate happens out1 and out2 acquire their values. How can this be corrected? TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return promise from `generate` function itself and export the `generate` function.

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
function generate() {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
    const prog = spawn('prog', []);

    prog.on('exit', function (code) {
      if (code != 0) {
        rej('Compilation failed');
      } else {
        const path1 = path.resolve(__dirname, 'out', 'file1');
        const path2 = path.resolve(__dirname, 'out', 'file2');
        const out1 = fs.readFileSync(path1, 'utf8');
        const out2 = fs.readFileSync(path2, 'utf8');
        res({ out1, out2 })
      }
    })
    prog.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    })
  })
}


module.exports = generate;
```

Now, when you use it you can use it as:

```
const fetch = require('./fetch');
fetch()
.then(data=>{
  ....
});
```

Comment: That is it. Thank you much!